# Why isn't it possible to run a 32-bit kernel on QEMU's raspi3 machine?

Tags: pi-3, qemu

I've been using QEMU for a few years now, and I know that when using raspi3 machine (in QEMU >= 3.x), you can't run a 32-bit kernel on it. You have to use raspi2 machine.

However, Cortex-A53 is supposed to support AArch64 as well as AArch32. Does it only mean that AArch64 is forced in QEMU's Cortex-A53 implementation so it can't actually run 32-bit instructions? Or is there another reason? What would be missing to have QEMU's Cortex-A53 running a 32-bit kernel?

Don't hesitate giving me deeply technical details for explanations (even going into QEMU's code)

Answer (score 1):

One obvious reason is that `raspi3` will load the kernel at the 0x80000 address, which is dedicated to the 64-bit kernel. If you load a 32-bit kernel at that address, it will fail to run because the absolute address values of all relative offsets will be wrong. The difference can be seen in "arm/raspi.c" file:

```
#define FIRMWARE_ADDR_2    0x8000 /* Pi 2 loads kernel.img here by default */
#define FIRMWARE_ADDR_3   0x80000 /* Pi 3 loads kernel8.img here by default */
...
binfo.entry = version==3? FIRMWARE_ADDR_3 : FIRMWARE_ADDR_2;
```

Comment: Yes but is it the only reason? If you look at bcm2836.c:31, you'll find a switch showing that `cortex-a7` is used for raspi2 while `cortex-a53` is used for raspi3. If I stupidly replace `cortex-a7` by `cortex-a53` would raspi2 machine still work?

Comment: @BenjaminBarrois No, I don't expect it to be the only reason. There is no way of finding them all without actually trying. In the end, there's nothing that really prevents you from emulating RPi3 in 32-bit mode. Nobody just did it because emulating RPi2 is good enough for most purposes.

Comment: @BenjaminBarrois And the change you suggest is not the same as emulating a 32-bit kernel in `raspi3`: I bet there are differences between the two machines besides the CPU.